# View doesn't reflect changes to CSS file

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm using a partial view and if I load a page with the partial view, with CSS stylesheet is reflected as it should be.

But if I delete the Header.css or change something in it, the styling will be the same, according to the following code:

```css
body {
}
#Header{
    margin:auto;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #45484d 0%,#000000 100%);
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
  
}
.MenuContainer{
 display:inline;

}
h3{
    display:inline;
}
#HeaderList {
      list-style-type:none;
     
   
}
.listForHead{
    display:inline;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Header.css" />
    <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="Header">
        <ul id="HeaderList">
            <li class="listForHead">               
                <div class="MenuContainer">
                    <h3>Main</h3>
                </div>        
            </li>
            <li class="listForHead">
                <div class="MenuContainer">
                    <h3>Methods of delivery</h3>
                </div>       
            </li>
            <li class="listForHead">
                <div class="MenuContainer">
                    <h3>About shop</h3>
                </div>       
            </li>
            <li class="listForHead">
                <div class="MenuContainer">
                    <h3>Contacts</h3>
                </div>       
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Usually, css files are cached by the navigator. If you are not using Bundles (http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) you have to clear cache the see the changes.

Comment: Thank's for hint it worked for me.I just putted date to link like this.<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Header.css?Wednesday 20th of July 2016 07:45:21 AM" />